# Taylor Polynomial Variable Question

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

When you have a polynomial that you set your function equal to in the taylor polynomial (centered around $x = a$) $$function = c_0+c_1(x-a)+c_2 (x-a)^2+...$$ why is your variable $(x-a)$.  Oddly enough, I used to know why but now I can't remember...  happens to me all the time.  Thanks!

Comment: Because if you plug in $x = a$, all of the polynomial terms vanish leaving you with $c_0 = f(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to expand in powers of a *small parameter* (so that the further you go in the series, the less significant the terms become). If $x$ is a small deviation from $a$ then it looks like $x=a+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon=x-a$ small.

Comment: so why must that small deviation, $\epsilon $, be your variable?

Comment: It's not the only way to develop a series expansion of a function, but it's the definition of "Taylor polynomial centered at $x=a$".  The motivation is that the polynomial agrees with $f$ at $x=a$, and that the later terms are less significant than the early terms.